# How to redirect user to a default error page when exception is raised in application_start?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, global-asax

Is there a way to redirect the user to an error page (view) when an exception is raised in application_start method of global.asax?   I get a Request object is null message when I try to do a redirect.  How would i handle this? I have to raise the exception if certain conditions are not met and I want the user to go to a specific View.
    My application is MVC3 based, btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application_Start` happens before ASP.Net starts processing the request.

You could set a global static flag to indicate the error condition, then handle `BeginRequest` and check the flag and redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion SLaks.  In anybody else has the same issue, I created a static variable NoLicenseFound in global.asax and set this value to true in the exception handler.  And I added the following code protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (noValidLicense) {
                string path = Request.ApplicationPath.ToString();
                Context.RewritePath(path + "/Errors/Error/NoLicense");
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) page.

The thing you are trying to do is possible via `Web.config` Just show what page to load when http error 500 occurs.

**Edit**

Sorry gave wrong url

Comment: Hi, I already have got error handlers for 404 and 500 using customErrors.  But this is a special case (licensing) and i need to be able to redirect the user to a special Error page instead of the 500 page.

Comment: Are you using IIS 7 with application pool integrated pipeline?